# Cyanogen installs bloatware automatically

Tags: applications, oneplus-one, bloatware, cyanogen-os

I'm using a OnePlus One, running Cyanogen OS 13.1 (build date June 16, 2016), stock, non-rooted.

I usually disable/uninstall all bloatware like a knee-jerk reaction.

But recently I've noticed that some of these apps re-enable or re-install automatically, namely *Cyanogen One Note Plugin, Email by Boxer*, etc.

How's this even possible? How may I disable/uninstall them permanently without rooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the apps in question appears to be user-uninstallable but keeps coming back, they might be in /vendor and /system/vendor. But if they are only available for disabling, then they're real system apps.
Either way, you'll need to gain root to access and eliminate them. As you have pointed out, unlike CM, COS doesn't come with root, so it might pose a problem.

Comment: They're uninstall-able. Then they automatically install themselves later.

Comment: Then it should be the former situation. Try a root-enabled file explorer (e.g. Root Explorer) and see what's inside the 2 folders. Note that you don't need to have root to _view_ the files.

Comment: You're right. I see in `/system/vendor/bundled-app` at least 10 such application packages.

Comment: The evil of COS and Cyngn as a corporate. Root and remove them if you want, or better, just install CM instead of COS. If you don't use these vendor apps bundled with COS then I don't see any advantages COS has over CM.

Comment: To clear your confusion, COS does not come with root. You may edit to update the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for notifying, all the more reason for me to avoid COS. Edited.

Answer (score -1):

Cyanogenmod is root by default it just needs to be turned on. and its going to install apps that are part of the OS like a email service.

Comment: That's what I thought. :(